# Add Images for my Sitecore Items through program

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am **creating Sitecore item programtically and want to add some images** for my item while creating programatically.It should get that image from Sitecore media, How to do that, need help.I Know how to do that using content item

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to assign an image to a field you have to add this code:

```cs
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
ImageField imageField = item.Fields["Your Image Field"];
imageField.MediaID = new ID("IMAGE ID");
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

If you want to create an image dynamically from a URL and then assign it to your item, you could use the following code:

```cs
var destinationPath = StringUtil.EnsurePostfix('/', imagesFolder.Paths.Path);
string imageName = ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(model.Title);
var options = new MediaCreatorOptions
{
    Database = ItemHelpers.GetMasterDatabase(),
    Versioned = false,
    Destination = destinationPath + imageName,
    FileBased = false,
    IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
    KeepExisting = true,
    AlternateText = imageName
};
try 
{
    WebClient cli = new WebClient();
    byte[] imgBytes = cli.DownloadData(imageUrl);
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        Item scImage = MediaManager.Creator.CreateFromStream(memStream, imageUrl, options);
        //Publish your Item
        //scImage.ID is the one you need to assign to you image field        
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Good to see that you take the time to answer even if the question is rather vague.